# ESB Rest call takes too much time to respond when traffic is high. What could be the reason?

Tags: c#, rest, networking, windows-phone-8.1, esb

I use below statement to make rest call from my mobile app.

```
HttpRequestMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(msg).AsTask(getTimeoutToken())
```

This works perfectly when traffic is less. Takes only milliseconds to 5 seconds. When traffic is high(number of users is high), this above statement takes too much of time. It takes 5 mins to 3 hours at peak times. I have set 300 seconds timeout in app which is also not working.

Can anyone suggest what could be the reason for this performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code hard to tell but some of the outlier could be

1) One of the reason could be during Traffic, there might be queuing happening on the server side which can cause significant latency.

2) There might be resource sharing or waiting on some resource which is locked by other requests. This can cause latency.

3) Your network bandwidth on the client side might be shared.

There can be other reasons as well.